# Is there a maximum size to a shared object file?

Tags: c, linux

I'm building an application that has a huge .so file - well over 2GB in size (stripped).
Are there limits to the size of an shared object file?
Because strace shows that the file is refused because it is too big.

My system currently is a 32-bit system, and I also wonder how much this changes when I would build for a 64-bit Linux system.

Comment: What kind of a .so is so big to be greater than 2GB?

Comment: Do you have a bunch of compiled resources in there or something?  A 2GB .so file is ridiculous.  This is one of those "if you have to ask you're probably doing something wrong" questions.

Comment: @EdS. I agree that there's something wrong - there's specific instrumentation in that .so file that is huge. If I strip the instrumentation out, the .so will be seriously smaller but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: What kind of instrumentation is so large?  I'm honestly curious.

Comment: @EdS. I'd prefer not to dive into details, but let's assume it is about 10 MB of symbol information each for about 2000 files.

Answer (score 2):

Since shared library is loaded completely into memory, I would highly recommend you to move your resources away to some external files. IMHO, 2GB is totally non-acceptable for a shared library, and will cause problems on low memory systems.

UPDATE:

Please ignore my first sentence about loading whole shared libraries into memory. As OP commented, shared libraries are indeed mmap'ed, and symbol pages are loaded on demand.

Comment: As far as I know (and that is what strace tells me), shared libraries are mmap'ed into memory. That suggests that most memory pages are loaded on demand.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your system's memory *.so links directly loaded with executable or system itself it can't load if you have low memory or OS allocates a lot of memory and if you build for 64-bit system it will expand more than 2 gb in size, because of adding some 64-bit flags and instructions.

Comment: My instrumentation won't grow larger on a 64-bit system, but indeed, the object files will.  I guess that a 64-bit system doesn't have any maximum memory limits anywhere in sight, so having a 3GB .so file on a 8GB 64-bit system should work, right?